# Installing a dimmer switch to multiple lights

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I have read the wiring configuration for a regular switch. Is this the same configuration for a dimmer switch? One switch, several lights. I don't need a three way switch do I?

Comment: If you have only 1 switch on the lights a standard dimmer is all that is needed. (SPST) Single pole single throw.

Answer (score 1):

A dimmer switch can replace a regular switch as long as the lights/light bulbs are dimmable.

A three way switch is a way to have two switches control one light.